# Do I need to re-register .NET 4.0 with IIS 7 after installing .NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm running IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008. It previously had .NET 4.0 installed with Application Pools for ASP.NET v4.0 and ASP.NET v4.0 Classic.

I've now installed .NET 4.5 (v4.0.30319) and I know that .NET 4.5 is an "in place upgrade", but do I need to re-register .NET 4.0 with IIS?

e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`

Comment: I don't think you need to - 4.5 is supposed to be a "drop-in" replacement to 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to re-register.  I recently installed .NET 4.5 and did not change any IIS settings.